# Hibernate: Getting result using a specific field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've been following a lot of tutorial on how to get a list of result by referencing a specific column in the table.

I have this table.

[image]

I want to get the list of result with a plan_code "TEST123"

This is my code:

PlanRepository.java

```
public interface PlanCoverageRepository extends CrudRepository<PlanCoverage, Long> {

    List<PlanCoverage> findAllByPlan_code(String plan_code);
}
```

PlanCoverageService.java

```
public interface PlanCoverageService {
    public List<PlanCoverage> getAllPlanCoverageByPlanCode(String plan_code);
}
```

PlanCoverageServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PlanCoverageServiceImpl implements PlanCoverageService {

    @Override
    public List<PlanCoverage> getAllPlanCoverageByPlanCode(String plan_code) {
        return (List<PlanCoverage>) planCoverageRepository.findAllByPlan_code(plan_code);
    }

}
```

PlanCoverageController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/admin")
public class PlanCoverageController {

    @Autowired
    PlanCoverageService planCoverageService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/Test/{plan_code}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView test(@PathVariable String plan_code) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        PlanCoverage planCoverage = (PlanCoverage) planCoverageService.getAllPlanCoverageByPlanCode(plan_code);
        model.addObject("planCoverageForm",planCoverage);
        model.setViewName("plan_coverage_form");
        return model;
    }   
}
```

PlanCoverage.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="plan_coverage")
public class PlanCoverage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long coverage_id;

    @Column(name="plan_code")
    private String plan_code;

    @Column(name="coverage_description")
    private String coverage_description;

    /..getters and setters

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="plan_code", referencedColumnName = "plan_code",insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Plan plan;

    public Plan getPlan() {
        return plan;
    }

    public void setPlan(Plan plan) {
        this.plan = plan;
    }


}
```

Please help me. I've been stuck with these for a few days and non of the tutorials seems to work on me. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Show the entity code also.

Comment: In your repository, could you try `findByPlanCode(String)` instead of your current method ?

Comment: @Arnaud I'm getting this error: "Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.rtc_insurance.repository.PlanCoverageRepository.findAllByPlanCode(java.lang.String)! No property code found for type Plan! Traversed path: PlanCoverage.plan.
"

Comment: @NiVeR I already posted it.

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up with the convention that spring boot is using to compose query methods. The case of the fields in the entity should follow the lower camel-case scheme, like so:

```
@Column(name="plan_code")
private String planCode;
```

and then the query method in `PlanCoverageRepository` should be:

```
List<PlanCoverage> findAllByPlanCode(String planCode);
```

Comment: does it differ when I use a different naming convention/ thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it now